# Removing an already picked phrase from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-animate, adobe

I am working with a code embedded in Adobe Animate CC. It works fine. But I want to make the already picked series to be removed from the array, so that I always pick a new series when I click the button. I have searched a lot, but not found anything that works yet. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
var myShows = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];


this.knapp.addEventListener("click", playClicked.bind(this));
function playClicked() {
    var show = myShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * myShows.length)];
    this.tekst.text = show

}
```

Comment: You might do like `var show = myShows.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myShows.length),1)[0];` so that the randomly selected show gets deleted from the `myShows` array and the next time it can not be picked.

Comment: Fantastic! It worked perfectly, and so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work.  Below is my attempt at putting your code back in:

```
var allShows = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];
var currentShow = allShows[0]; //Just to initialize 


// Filter out the one you have selected
function getAvailableShows() {
  return allShows.filter(function(e) { return e !== currentShow })
}

function playClicked() {
  // make a pool - current one playing
  var availableShows = getAvailableShows(); 

  // choose one from random
  var show = availableShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableShows.length)]; 

  // update current show
  currentShow = show;

  // updae text
  this.tekst.text = show;
}

this.knapp.addEventListener("click", playClicked.bind(this));
```

Here's a code pen showing that it works via console log. 
https://codepen.io/easement/pen/MbNwdw

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your time and try to help me. Although your code seems to do the same as the one I already have. The picked shows reappears. Do you think it will be possible to pick all the shows in a random order without picking one show twice or more?